# Internal app without public URL in Django

Tags: django

The ultimate aim is to have a flexible mechanism in a Django web app for rendering PDF files. To achieve this I have designed a mechanism using Jinja2 for templating a TeX input file with a given dictionary. The template is served by a custom jinja loader via the Django ORM. The TeX file is then compiled using pdflatex.

I have made a separate app in Django in which the model for the LaTeX templates is defined. In this app there is a class in which the rendering takes place. In the end a HttpResponse object is created with which the PDF is returned.

For me this sounds like a classical Django view: it takes a request and delivers a response. However I would like to prevent anybody from using this view to generate arbitrary PDFs just by calling an URL.

How do I do that? Write a view without referencing it in the URL configuration and then call it directly from other views?

Comment: Yes. this is essentially the same as a view , just that it is not accessible via a URL. (We use a lot of `util` package helper methods which do exactly this. )

Comment: so you call the view directly after an import via its dotted path?

Comment: The package can be in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then it is just a simple import. `from util.helper1 import blah`

Comment: Right. As I am using Django models it has to be registered in `INSTALLED_APPS`, otherwise packaging it and installing it with pip and using plain `import` statements would work as well.